# troubles with SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I tried to overload the operator- so that it applies set difference to its arguments. Since I couldn't figure out how to restrict it to STL containers only (because If I dont, it will overwriter every operator- it seems), I tried to restrict it to set and vector only, because I'd use it with those two.
Here is my code:

```
#define RANGE(x) (x).begin(), (x).end()

template<class T>
struct is_STL_container
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<class T, typename alloc>
struct is_STL_container<std::vector<T, alloc>>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

template<class T, class comp, typename alloc>
struct is_STL_container<std::set<T, comp, alloc>>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};


template <class T1, class T2,
class std::enable_if<is_STL_container<T1>::value && is_STL_container<T2>::value, T1>::type>
T1 operator - (const T1 &l, const T2 &r)
{
    assert(typeid(T1::value_type) == typeid(T2::value_type));

    std::vector<T1::value_type> result;
    std::set_difference(RANGE(l), RANGE(r), std::back_inserter(result));
    return T1(RANGE(result));
}
```

But when I try to compile my program i get the following errors:

```
Error   2   error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\algorithm    3071    1   TrafficLight
Error   1   error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::less<void>::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) const'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\algorithm    3071    1   TrafficLight
```

I can't figure out the problem
Im using VS2013

Best Regards
Uzaku

Comment: This is a bit of a nitpick, but you could derive your basic `is_STL_container` from `std::false_type` and your specialised ones from `std::true_type` (both in `<type_traits>`), if you wanted to.  They were pretty much made for switching based on a bool/enable_if/anything of the sort, I believe.  (They're instantiations of `std::integral_constant`, which is designed to allow you to treat a value as a type.)  Not worth changing your code for now, but it might be useful to remember in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of syntax errors with your code. The following example below works.

**Note:** The `operator-` below is templated on `T` instead of `T1` and `T2` because I wasn't sure you actually wanted to allow `operator-` to work when using vectors of different types, e.g. `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<double>`.

#### Example Code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

#define RANGE(x) (x).begin(), (x).end()

template<class T>
struct is_STL_container
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<class T, typename alloc>
struct is_STL_container<std::vector<T, alloc>>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

template<class T, class comp, typename alloc>
struct is_STL_container<std::set<T, comp, alloc>>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<is_STL_container<T>::value && is_STL_container<T>::value, T>::type
operator-(const T &l, const T &r)
{
    T result;
    std::set_difference(RANGE(l), RANGE(r), std::back_inserter(result));
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<int> b = { 2, 3, 4 };
    std::vector<int> r = a - b;
    for (const auto& v : r)
    {
        std::cout << v << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Example Output

```
1 5
```

[Live Example](https://ideone.com/IWHpbd)

---

#### Edit 1

**Note:** As pointed out in the comments by @StoryTeller, templating `operator-` on just `T` would prevent the valid usage of `operator-` between `std::vector<int>` and `std::set<int>` (as attempted by the OP). The following code uses `T1` and `T2` to resolve this issue.

#### Example Code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>

#define RANGE(x) (x).begin(), (x).end()

template<class T>
struct is_STL_container
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<class T, typename alloc>
struct is_STL_container<std::vector<T, alloc>>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

template<class T, class comp, typename alloc>
struct is_STL_container<std::set<T, comp, alloc>>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};


template <class T1, class T2>
typename std::enable_if<is_STL_container<T1>::value && is_STL_container<T2>::value, T1>::type
operator-(const T1 &l, const T2 &r)
{
    assert(typeid(typename T1::value_type) == typeid(typename T2::value_type));

    T1 result;
    std::set_difference(RANGE(l), RANGE(r), std::back_inserter(result));
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<int> b = { 2, 3, 4 };
    std::set<int> c = { 2, 3, 4 };

    std::vector<int> r = a - b;
    for (const auto& v : r)
    {
        std::cout << v << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";

    r = a - c;
    for (const auto& v : r)
    {
        std::cout << v << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Example Output

```
1 5 
1 5
```

[Live Example](https://ideone.com/ermlO6)

Comment: The changes you made are unnecessarily limiting. `std:set_difference` can quite easily accept iterators of different types.

Comment: @StoryTeller I was actually editing the answer to include a note about my usage of `T` versus `T1` and `T2` when you left your comment.

Comment: Not just vectors of different types, but different datatypes altogether.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, you're correct. As written it would exclude using `operator-` with `std::vector<int>` and `std::set<int>`.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thank you for pointing that out, I added an edit.

Answer (score 3):

`std::enable_if` is a metafuction returning a type (defaulted to void).
As such, you main `operator-` statement is malformed.

You must change the template `class` parameter to look like this

```
class = typename std::enable_if_t<is_STL_container<T1>::value &&
                                  is_STL_container<T2>::value>
```

Or this:

```
class = typename std::enable_if<is_STL_container<T1>::value &&
                                is_STL_container<T2>::value>::type
```

You can find the fixed program [here](http://ideone.com/AuemP3).

Answer (score 1):

Consider this definition

```
template <class T1, class T2, class int> int operator- ...
```

This is blatantly incorrect, right? But you have written only slightly more complicated version of it.

What you neef is

```
template <class T1, class T2>
typename std::enable_if<whatever>::type
operator- ...
```

Comment: actually the first code of yours isn't a very good example while nothing is stopping you from having anonymous template argument...

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg it's possible. you would need to write `class=defaultarg`.

Comment: by anonymous I meant without a name like in case of your third template argument - not with default value...

Comment: @WojciechFrohmber sorry don't understand this.

Comment: In other words your code: 'template <class T1, class T2, int>' is perfectly legal while the third argument can be of type constexpr int but have no label...

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg oh you mean non-type parameter. Fixing.